# Send APDU commands to SIM card in android 11

Tags: android, apdu, sim-card

In Android 11 (API level 30), these functions have been deprecated:

- iccExchangeSimIO
- iccTransmitApduBasicChannel
- iccTransmitApduLogicalChannel

Is there any way to send an APDU command to a SIM card via the Android API above API level 30?

I have studied the Android API 30, but have not found any references to APDU commands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that [Google didn't actually intend to deprecate the feature, according to their support statements](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/236727027#comment3). However, they mistakenly left the deprecated tag in subsequent API versions. They issued a "nofix" status, likely because someone didn't respond appropriately when asked "for more information."

A [subsequent bug report was filed](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/230013915), inquiring about the methods developers should adopt as alternatives. In typical issue-tracker fashion, it was marked "fixed" with the comment "The development team has resolved the issue you reported." This directly contradicts both the "nofix" of the earlier report and the persistent deprecated tag.

In all likelihood, they won't take action unless another bug report is filed. But when you do, you risk being scorned because "the bug was already reported" or seeing your report remain unresolved for years. I could've probably resolved the issue in the time it took to pen this, but that would mean a pull request, and frankly, my stomach isn't up to that right now.

While "deprecated" implies a suggestion not to use the feature, the absence of suggested alternatives means I wouldn't be overly concerned about it.

Comment: If TheDailyWTF ever wants another category, bug database fuckups would be a great one. The Android bug database is definitely not an outlier.

Comment: If somebody sees this as AI generated: that's correct, I asked ChatGPT to rewrite my original answer to see what it can do, see the history. Trust me, ChatGPT would not have come up with the answer, nor would it use "scorned" or "stomach it" in the text; I had to force those through.

Comment: Thank you very much!!

I guess I found an alternative in omapi package: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/se/omapi/Channel#transmit (byte[])